# Package Manager console throws an error and can't enable migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Package Manager console throws an error and can't enable migrations.

The error message is:

> The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an
>   exception.

This is my model [Employee]:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCCMigration.Models
{
    public enum Gender {Male,Female,Other }
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmpId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Employee Name")]
        [Required]
        public string EmpName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Department")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Department DepartmentName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Department
    { 
        [Key]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Department Name")]
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Also my model [EmployeeContext]:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCCMigration.Models
{
    public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeContext() : base("name=EmployeeContext") {


        }

        public DbSet<Department> department { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> employee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString=" Data Source=LAPTOP-TL0BA7EM\LOCAL; Initial Catalog= EmployeeContext2016; user id = sa; Password= aaa; Integrated Security=False" providerName ="System.Data.Client"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration
```

>

And after I type `enable-migrations -contexttypename EmployeeContext`, it throws an error message as mentioned above:

> The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an
>   exception.

Kindly help. I'm a beginner in C# / ASP.NET, and the Code First migration, and I'm trying something out for educational purposes. Thank you very much!

Comment: you don't need to specify the connection name. And if you do you just pass the name not 'name=...'

Comment: Try using `public EmployeeContext() : base("EmployeeContext")`. EF automatically retrieve connection string associated by `name` attribute in web.config.